# SSRS 2019 logon failure when accessing through HTTPS

Tags: authentication, reporting-services

I have a question regarding SQL Server Reporting Services 2019:

We have received a HTTPS-certificate and added a URL for both Web Service and Web Portal. When we try to access either /Reports or /ReportServer on HTTP we can get through with no problem, but when we try to access on HTTPS then we are met with a logon dialog which will give three attempts at log on before displaying a white page. All attempts at entering a valid combination of user name and password returns a 401 error.

We've tried removing and reinserting all bindings for HTTP, HTTPS, SSL, changing logon mechanism in the config file to use Kerberos, NTLM or a combination of those but nothing works.

Does anyone what the source of this problem might be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out what the problem was. Authentication issues did not behave the same for HTTP and HTTPS. My test user wasn't a member of the correct user group. Once we gave it "System User" access then we could log in.